# Return string element from array given index

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, element

I have the following code:

```
     Dim CurrMonth As Integer
     Dim MonthPos As Variant
     Dim CurrPos As Integer
     
     
     CurrMonth = Month(Date) - 1
     MonthPos = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
```

Could anyone provide guidance on how I would be able to get (in this case) the string element from the Array MonthPos given the index CurrMonth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/vba-array-tutorial/#One_Dimensional_Array offers following example:

```
Private Sub arrayExample3()
Dim thirdQuarter(13 To 15) As String 'creates array with index 13,14,15
thirdQuarter(13) = "July"
thirdQuarter(14) = "Aug"
thirdQuarter(15) = "Sep"
MsgBox "Third Quarter in calendar " & " " & thirdQuarter(13) & " " &
        thirdQuarter(14) & " " & thirdQuarter(15)
End Sub
```

So for your case should be:

```
MonthPos(CurrMonth)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, use the next adapted way:

```
Sub extractMonth()
  Dim CurrMonth As Long, MonthPos As Variant, CurrPos As Integer, prevMonth
 
     CurrMonth = Month(Date) - 1
     MonthPos = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
     prevMonth = MonthPos(CurrMonth - 1) '- 1 because it is a zero based 1D array...
     Debug.Print prevMonth 'the previous month (I could see Month(Date) - 1) and I supposed that this is needed.
                           'otherwise, you should simple use MonthPos(CurrMonth), for the current month
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the array you can also use

```
Format$(date,"MMMM")
```

or if you need the previos month then

```
Format$(DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date)-1,1),"MMMM")
```

to get the name of the month in the language of the operating system.

Comment: ... or `Application.Text` to get the month name in VBA's EN-US standard +:) - Fyi Added approach via evaluation allowing any months increments|decrements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Excel (to evaluate the months name array in one go) the following approach allows to input any increments or decrements as optional second argument:

```
Function getMonth(currMonth As Long, Optional MonthOffset As Long = 0)
'a) build array of month names via evaluation (Excel)
    Dim months(): months = [Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),"mmmm")]
'b) calculate wanted month
    currMonth = (currMonth + MonthOffset + 12) Mod 12
    If currMonth = 0 Then currMonth = 12
'c) return month name
    getMonth = months(currMonth)
End Function
```

**Example call**

Simply pass a possible decrement as 2nd argument:

```
   Debug.Print getMonth(1)              ' ~~> returns January
   Debug.Print getMonth(1,-1)           ' ~~> returns December
   'assuming call as of 5/31 2022, i.e. equalling getMonth(5) 
   Debug.Print getMonth(Month(Date))    ' ~~> returns May
   Debug.Print getMonth(Month(Date),-1) ' ~~> returns April
```